# plasma-nm on ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10

I installed `plasma-nm` from Ubuntu Center, after that when i search for it with name `kde-nm-connection-editor` in dash it doesn't display any thing that matches with my search
So how can i use it after install it ?
Or there is other application like `plasma-nm` ?

Answer (score 1):

**I found the solution.**

press **Alt+F2** to bring up the dash, do not click on the icon directly from Unity Launcher and then write and click on **kde-nm-connection-editor**